# Chromebook chroot crouton several instances of linux at the same time

Tags: linux, google-chrome-os

Does anyone know if it possible to run two instances of different operating systems on a Chromebook with chroot/crouton. I have read that is possible to have different crouton "session" but there nothing out there about running ChromeOS with two or more chroot/crouton instances of an operating systems side by side simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Launching a second instance kills X in the first. Check the relevant crosh tab for messages. Maybe X could be configured correctly but research...

Comment: this happens even if they are different chroot?
I've read somewhere it was possible...

Comment: Is this [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176880/crouton-with-more-than-one-os) answer to the question?

Comment: areyou trying to lauch diferent "installs" or the sameone?